# Cross sectional survey - difference in difference campaign evaluation

Tags: causality, difference-in-difference, causal-inference

I would like to use two cross sectional surveys to evaluate the impact of a media campaign on public opinions. The problem is how to identify the "untreated" at baseline? Technically everyone is untreated and I will be using a recall question in the endline survey to separate the "untreated" from the "treated"? My question is basically should I use something other that DiD for this? How do I get two groups at baseline?

Thanks!

Comment: Some descriptions of the surveys you have would bring more clarity to your question.

Comment: Thanks @HerrK. ! Still designing the surveys but likely two cross sectional surveys one before the campaign is launched and endline after it is over. The outcome of interest would be an index variable to measure a certain attitude. Thinking about how I would analyze this in a defensible approach,  I am struggling with figuring out how to do a diff-in-diff when I do not know at baseline which observations will be treated? Does my concern make sense? Since the treatment variable will be exposure to the campaign and that will be measured at endline.

Comment: So in the diff-in-diff when I create a variable to identify the treatment/control, I won't have any treatment variables at baseline. Would that work? Is there something I am missing?